# finding parts of a website with selenium when the div class' names change temporarily

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to scrape a website but it uses some kind of software that changes the class' names of the divs. As the technique I am using is `find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='classname']")`  each time the div class names change my solution fail. The part of the website that I am interested looks like this:

```
<div class="classname1"> #List of items start
 <div class="classname2"> #I want it (this is special cause its like the title)
 </div>
 <div class="classname3"> # the first item (i want it cause the divs inside it is the information of the item
  <div class = "classname4">
  </div>
  ...
  more <div class> inside
 </div>
 <div class="classname3"> #second item I am also interested in(same as the first one, i want it cause the divs inside it is the information of the item)
  <div class="classname5">
  </div>
  ...
  more <div class> inside
 </div>
# and so on
...
</div>
```

Is there another approach to localize this items but avoiding this problem?

Comment: Using contains,starts-with If it uses a unique classname that changes.

Comment: Is the sample html in your question really representative of your real html? For example, does the `div` with the item you want always have a `div` child you don't want?

Comment: Which _classname_ changes?

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I don't understand what you mean, could you attach a sample code?

Comment: @JackFleeting I have edited the html in order to give a better perspective of what the original html is. Just to sum up, there is a first div which contains all the items, which are after the div which contains the title text. Each item is a div with classname3 which contains some other divs with the text information of the item. My idea is to find the div of the item and apply a .text. So I would just need to find the divs with the classnames: 1,2, and 3.

Comment: @DebanjanB all of them, but I forgot to say that classnames of each item are equal.